# Text to image GANs and failure

Tags: generative-adversarial-networks, image-generation

My knowledge of GANs is relatively basic at the moment but I seem to remember reading somewhere that GANs that generate images from a text prompt, when they fail to understand some of the text/words render those text/words in the image itself instead of interpreting and rendering what they refer to - this is apparently a known bug or failure.

Can somebody confirm that this is true or false? And if possible provide a link to writing about it that will allow me to verify the details e.g. if its specific to a type of GAN, version etc. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: do you mean DALL-E https://openai.com/blog/dall-e/ ?

Comment: Yes but I'm using VQGAN + CLIP at the moment and I can see what seems to corresponds to the behaviour I've described above. I just need to to find details that this is a known bug/behaviour.